# Как изменить указатель на объект? - С++

Tags: c++, указатели

Я создаю 2 объекта разных классов, и указатель на какой-либо объект.
http://snap.ashampoo.com/El2QRRNh
Как создать указатель на объект, который можно будет менять в зависимости от нужной фигуры?
http://snap.ashampoo.com/g28QYe0T

Comment: Код следует добавлять в виде кода, а не в виде левых ссылок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте общий базовый класс для фигур

```
class BaseFigure {...};

class SomeFigure: public BaseFigure {...};
class AnotherFigure: public BaseFigure {...};
```

тогда:

```
SomeFigure some;
AnotherFigure another;

BaseFigure *figure = &some; // OK
figure = &another;          // OK
```